# Trivality of tangent bundle and complex structure

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimensions $2n$, and suppose 
$$TM \equiv M \times \mathbb R^{2n}. $$

Does it follow that $M$ admits a complex structure?

It seems like the almost complex structure defined by taking the standard (after choosing a global frame $\{ v_1, \dots, v_n\}$) one at each point on $TM$ $p \in M$: $$J_p: T_pM=\mathbb R^{2n} \rightarrow T_pM=\mathbb R^{2n},$$
given by
$$J_p = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & I \\
    -I & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
is a good candidate for a complex structure. But how can we know if this is integrable? I am aware of the Newlander–Nirenberg theorem, but am wondering if there are other ways to know if I can't compute that.

Thanks!

Comment: There are example of parallelizable manifold with no complex structure, see this [short paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938376900495)

Comment: Also possibly of interest, the famous Kodaira-Thurston nilmanifold (the first published example of a closed manifold that admits both symplectic and complex structures, but does not admit a Kähler structure) is of type (iii) as listed in Theorem 2 of that paper.